# Options error: Unrecognized option or missing or extra parameter(s) in server.ovpn:78: ca (2.6_beta1) Use --help for more information

Tags: networking, ssh, vpn, openvpn, windows-server-2008-r2

getting this error when starting server.

```
Options error: Unrecognized option or missing or extra parameter(s) in server.ovpn:78: ca (2.6_beta1)
Use --help for more information.
```

just using sample config file I modified. thank you in advance

```
port 1194

proto udp

dev tun

ca C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\pki\\server.crt

cert C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\pki\\issued\\server.crt

key C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\pki\\private\\server.key 

dh C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\pki\\dh2048.pem

server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0

ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt

keepalive 10 120

tls-auth ta.key 0 # This file is secret

cipher AES-256-CBC

persist-key

persist-tun

status openvpn-status.log

verb 3

explicit-exit-notify 1
```

Comment: it might help to give the filename of this - the error indicates the problem is at line 78 of server.ovpn I think, and this seems too short

Answer (score 1):

The following:

```
ca C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\pki\\server.crt

cert C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\pki\\issued\\server.crt

key C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\pki\\private\\server.key

dh C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\pki\\dh2048.pem
```

Should be:

```
ca “C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\pki\\server.crt”

cert “C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\pki\\issued\\server.crt”

key “C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\pki\\private\\server.key”

dh “C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\pki\\dh2048.pem”
```

Comment: thank you very much, I'm getting there. now I get the following.                                   2022-12-12 20:40:38 WARNING: --topology net30 support for server configs with IPv4 pools will be removed in a future release. Please migrate to --topology subnet as soon as possible.
2022-12-12 20:40:38 DEPRECATED OPTION: --cipher set to 'AES-256-CBC' but missing in --data-ciphers (AES-256-GCM:AES-128-GCM). OpenVPN ignores --cipher for cipher negotiations. 
2022-12-12 20:40:38 Cannot pre-load keyfile (ca.key)
2022-12-12 20:40:38 Exiting due to fatal error

Comment: I don’t answer questions contained in a comment. I have found if I do that, the number of questions that are ask, are endless. Your question was about a specific error which I have answered.

Comment: my apologies...

Comment: @RH and also JG  -- see if the later question by this author is essentially a duplicate.

Comment: @John - Can’t mark a comment as a duplicate, also can’t answer a question in a comment, went looking for an answer, wasn’t expecting to find the solution

Comment: There was a new question (not comment) by this Author within 30 minutes later